# Why does this code need an array offset?

Tags: php

Why do we use this type of code in CodeIgniter? Why don't we just use `return $data;` instead of `return $data[0];`; is it any difference between the two?

```
<?php

public function getUserById($id)
{
    $st = $this->db->select('user.*')->from('user')->where('id', $id)->get();
    $data = $st->result_array();
    return $data[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that `id` is **not unique**, in that case your query could return an array of multiple matching rows.

By returning `$data[0]` you are returning the first matched row only.

If you returned `$data` you would have access to the entire array of matched rows.